# add_filter the_content in functions.php not working

Tags: plugins, filters, the-content, seo

I want to add_filter for the_content in functions.php of my theme.
I have added code which just display echo but it seams that my filter is not applied.

```
function add_mod_hatom_data($content) {
   // $t = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
   //$author = get_the_author();
   // $title = get_the_title();
   //if(is_single()) {
    echo 'perrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr';
   //   $content .= '<div class="hatom-extra"><span class="entry-title">'.$title.'</span> was last modified: <span class="updated"> '.

//$t.'</span> by <span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">'.$author.'</span></span></div>';
   // }
    return $content;
    }

 add_filter('the_content', 'add_mod_hatom_data');
```

I have tried to call it like this :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_mod_hatom_data', 99);
```

or change position to be on top of functions.php with no success.

Do I need to enable somewhere add_filter or it is overridden by some other function ?
NOTE: In my single post template I have :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>      
            <div id="content" class="clearfix row">
                <div id="main" class="col-sm-8 clearfix" role="main">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                        <header>



                            <div class="page-header clip_content single-post">
                                            <div class="page-header">
                                                <h1 class="single-title-wg" itemprop="headline">
                                                                                                        <?php $category = get_the_category();
                                                                                                        if ($category[0]) {
                                                                                                          echo '<b>'.$category[0]->cat_name.' '.$post->ID.'</b>';
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                        ?>
                                                </h1>
                                                                                            <h4 class="single-title" itemprop="headline">
                                                                                            <p class="lead">                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                                        </p>
                                                                                                           </h4>

                                            </div>


                <div class="item_footer">
                                                        </div>            
                                <?php $category = get_the_category();
                                if ($category[0]) {?>
                                <p class="authorParagraph">
                                    <?php echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category[0]->term_id) . '" class="clearfix">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</a></p>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        </header> <!-- end article header -->

                        <footer>
                            <!-- <?php the_tags('<p class="tags"><span class="tags-title">' . __("Tags","wpbootstrap") . ':</span> ', ' ', '</p>'); ?> -->
                        </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                    </article> <!-- end article -->



                    <?php endwhile; ?>          

                    <?php else : ?>

                    <article id="post-not-found">
                        <header>
                            <h1><?php _e("Not Found", "wpbootstrap"); ?></h1>
                        </header>
                        <section class="post_content">
                            <p><?php _e("Sorry, but the requested resource was not found on this site.", "wpbootstrap"); ?></p>
                        </section>
                        <footer>
                        </footer>
                    </article>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div> <!-- end #main -->

            </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please enhance the source of the loop inside the template. Do you use the default wp functions `the_content()` to get the content on front end? If not, then is it not possible to fire to this hook. Maybe you must enhance your solution for output the content via  `apply_filter`. See also the [documentation of the hook](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/the_content?version=3.9&file=wp-includes/post-template.php).

Comment: that 'echo' possibly ends up somewhere before the html of the site is output; try to add the string to the $content like `return 'rrr'.$content;`

Comment: Problem is that my filter is not applied. I have just comment out code in function and put echo to prove that function is not called in single post.

Comment: @bueltge I suspect you are going in good direction but I am not sure that I understand. I think that problem is related because in single post template I use the_post() and there is no the_content() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the single post template is called the loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Within the loop you need to call in the content:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Replace your single post template with this and see if it works now:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>      
<div id="content" class="clearfix row">
    <div id="main" class="col-sm-8 clearfix" role="main">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

            <header>



                <div class="page-header clip_content single-post">
                                <div class="page-header">
                                    <h1 class="single-title-wg" itemprop="headline">
                                        <?php $category = get_the_category();
                                        if ($category[0]) {
                                          echo '<b>'.$category[0]->cat_name.' '.$post->ID.'</b>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </h1>
                                    <h4 class="single-title" itemprop="headline">
                                    <p class="lead"> <?php the_title(); ?></p></h4>
                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                                </div>


    <div class="item_footer">
                                            </div>            
                    <?php $category = get_the_category();
                    if ($category[0]) {?>
                    <p class="authorParagraph">
                        <?php echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category[0]->term_id) . '" class="clearfix">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</a></p>';
                        }
                        ?>
                </div>
                </div>

            </header> <!-- end article header -->

            <footer>
                <!-- <?php the_tags('<p class="tags"><span class="tags-title">' . __("Tags","wpbootstrap") . ':</span> ', ' ', '</p>'); ?> -->
            </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

        </article> <!-- end article -->



        <?php endwhile; ?>          

        <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-not-found">
            <header>
                <h1><?php _e("Not Found", "wpbootstrap"); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <section class="post_content">
                <p><?php _e("Sorry, but the requested resource was not found on this site.", "wpbootstrap"); ?></p>
            </section>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </article>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- end #main -->

</div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have title and content same so I just need to replace the_title with the_content.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the variable '$content' is empty. The way you are using this filter is correct. Instead of 'echo' put your values in the '$content variable' and then the 'return $content' will in effect echo this out to the page. Try this:

```
function add_mod_hatom_data($content) {
   // $t = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
   //$author = get_the_author();
   // $title = get_the_title();
   //if(is_single()) {
    $content = 'perrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr';
   //   $content .= '<div class="hatom-extra"><span class="entry-title">'.$title.'</span> was last modified: <span class="updated"> '.

//$t.'</span> by <span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">'.$author.'</span></span></div>';
   // }
    return $content;
    }

 add_filter('the_content', 'add_mod_hatom_data');
```

Comment: This also does not work. I have comment out code in this function and put echo to prove that function will not be called. I have tested also your code 'perrrrr...' is not displayed even I put it in $content variable. 
I suspect this is related because in template of single post I have the_post() and not the_content() or something ?

Comment: Can you add in your single post template code so we can see. (All of it)

Comment: Sure thing. I have updated question with simplified template.

Answer (score -1):

Use this (the_content filter has only one parameter and you must use 1)

```
 add_filter('the_content', 'add_mod_hatom_data', 1);
```